# windows update service starts automatically after I've disabled it

Tags: windows, service, update

Since the microsoft fixes/updates on the servers in our organization are managed by another group via SCCM, I have disabled the Windows Update and the Background Intellingent Transfer services and deleted the C:\windows\software distribution\ in order to recover couple of Gigs.
The problem is the system starts automatically the services without human intervention.

Event viewer capture:
The Windows Update service entered the running state.
Log Name: System
Source: Service Control Manager
Event ID: 7036
OpCode: Info
Logged: 08/12/2016 15:32:06
Task Category: None
Keywords: Classic
Computer: CTX******

Does anyone knows why the services are switching to running state automatically and how to prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: go to group policy editor - either local or domain - under computer configuration->administrative templates->windows components->windows update now you got all settings which you need. After this I know it sounds weird even if your not in domain do in elevated cmd/powershell - gpupdate /force.

Comment: Don't subvert the work of your co-workers. Instead, have an honest conversation with them about what you're experiencing and then work towards a mutually-agreeable solution. To put a finer point on it, policy circumvention questions are off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `rsop.msc` and check whether in existing policies settings related to Windows Update client work.

Comment: Yes, it seems there's a Windows Update policy. Thanks!